# Routing on internal Server using Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, routes, gitlab

I'm fairly new to Linux servers and networking and I'm trying to setup a server for my own GitLab and to host a node.js Backend und a React.js Frontend.

I did set up a Linux server using Ubuntu 20.04 and installed Gitlab there.

I can access my Gitlab with my internal IP, that works fine. What I'm trying to achieve is routing on this server so that I can run several applications.

I'm trying to reach my git for example with "myipaddress/git", my backend with "myipaddress/api" and so on but I can't find anything that helps, maybe I just don't have proper keywords for a good old google search. Does anyone have an idea where I can start?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not a routing problem because you are able to access your "myipaddress/git"!

Due to GitLab Doc (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#how-to-use-the-api) the tried URL "myipaddress/api" is not valid. Use "myipaddress/api/v4/projects" instead in case of non authenticated requests.

To authenticated requests you'll need an OAuth2 tokens.